# How i will make search with custom taxonomy (product, category, user, custom post type)search WordPress using function without any plugin

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

How I will make custom taxonomy search WordPress as lime the image using a function without any plugin

when someone select **product** from dropdown it will search for the **product** 
when someone select **category** and type search field it will search **category name**
when select **author** it will search **user**

[image: ss]

Comment: I would suggest using a solution from - https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/228663/33966

Answer (score 0):

The search form is found within your theme's `searchform.php` file. If your theme does not have one, creating one will override the WordPress default. You might do something like:

```
<li id="search">
  <label for="s">Search:</label>   
  <form id="searchform" method="get" action="/index.php">
    <div>
      <input type="text" name="s" id="s" size="15" />
      <select name="searchcat">
        <option value="0">Search Posts & Pages<option>
        <option value="1">Search WooCommerce Products</option>
        <option value="2">Search Custom Post Type</option>
      </select>
      <input type="submit" value="Search" />
    </div>
  </form>
</li>
```

The search results are found in the your theme's `search.php` file. Again, if your theme does not have one, you can create one to override the default functionality.

Then, based on what it selected from the pulldown, you can create different queries to retrieve the required results.

Comment: yes but this is not a solution because there will also change URL PAttren I will select to search type from the dropdown and then type the search text  you just send me HTML that is already I did